# Android : how to merge two TEXT VIEWS when needed, according to a condition?

Tags: text, merge, view

I programming an app to my university that require me to design a time table for each student.
So I used table view with text views in every row,text views refer to the time of student's classes (each text view represents one hour like from 9am to 10am). So I can retrieve the values from database and set them into the test views. But the main problem is maybe student has class of tow hours.

How can I merge two text views together to represent the time of class of two hours?

OR

is there better way than the table view ?

and thank you in advance.

Comment: Let me get this right, you have `tv1.Text = 8` and `tv2.Text=10` and you only want to have a single `TextView` to show...what? I don't quite understand, what should be in your merged `TextView` ?

Comment: yes, I want to have these two tv1 and tv2 into one TextView !!

Comment: I dont know if thats possible ,but is there any better way to design time table rather than using TableView ??

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you can use the `TableLayout` for that. The `TableLayout` can be constructed dynamically using `TableRow` items. Each `TableRow` can be added to the `TableLayout` and in the `TableRow` you can add your controls (like `TextViews`). I am presuming that you have some data and you are constructing your table based on that data. Anyway, it will be something like this:

```
TextView tv1 = new TextView();
TextView tv2 = new TextView();
if(some condition){
  tv1.Text = "whatever text you need to add";
  //add tv1 to your layout
}
else{
  tv1.Text = "some text for tv1";
  tv2.Text = "some text for tv2";
  //add both textviews to your layout
}
```

I can't write you a more complex piece of code because I am at work and I don't have Eclipse installed. But if you want to take a more deeper look into how to do this take a look at [this](http://huuah.com/using-tablelayout-on-android/)

Hope it will help you.